# Multiple explorer.exe processes consuming large amounts of memory

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, anti-virus

I'm pretty sure my laptop has been infected with a virus but I can't identify it or remove it.

## Symptoms:

- Multiple explorer.exe processes being spawned some consuming lots of memory
  [image]
- When I launch IE the history shows lots of sites/pages I've never visited.
  [image]
- When I shutdown I see flashes of images that look like they are from web sites filled with ads.

I'm guessing the background explorer.exe process are visiting sites to either increase views or click-thrus and to make it look like it's coming from different computers.

## What I've tried:

- Downloaded CCleaner and remove temp internet files, etc
- Downloaded and run multiple anti-virus programs including McAfee, AVG, Malwarebytes and Ad-aware

  - Scans have been run in both normal Windows and safe-mode.
  - Most of the AV programs haven't found much. Mostly bad cookies which I think are related to the hidden browsing going on.
  - AVG did find an HTML/Framer and Java/Downloader virus on first run but claimed it cleaned it and then ran clean on the next runs.
- I can end the explorer.exe process from Task Manager but new spawn again. If delete all explorer.exe process then eventually I hit the real one and the task bar, etc goes away.

  - I've also download Process Explorer to try and find the parent process but the parent looks like the system process:
    [image]

I am reaching the point where I think a clean install is my only option but hoped there is an solution to remove this without resorting to that.

Comment: You could sift through the DLLs the rogue processes have loaded. That might help identify the malware, at least. Still, I think it'd be better to nuke the system.

Comment: Did you try scanning your system with [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/)? Also, check [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) if you haven't already.

Comment: Does this problem surface when `Safe Mode` is used?

Comment: No I don't see the multiple processes in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try the [Combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) tool next. It's a very powerful tool, so make sure you have backups of your important data. It works on Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8; make sure you run it as an Administrator though. This tool goes through many more checks than typical anti virus programs

**DISCLAIMER**: I only use this product, I do not help develop it or receive compensation for telling others of its use. It works well for me, so I am offering it as a possible solution.

Comment: Running this over night. Will check the results in the morning. If that doesn't work I think reinstall is my only option.

Comment: ComboFix hung after rebooting (sat there all night). Ended up going with re-imaging the system.

Comment: That sucks, sorry to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I've seen this multiple explorer.exe before and even if you kill the processes, they still come back.  Malwarebytes is the only software that fixed the virus.

Comment: OP already tried Malwarebytes